# not able to use svn command from terminal in Mac OS 10.8

Tags: macos, svn, terminal

Team

SVN commands were working fine in terminal.
I have uninstalled and installed the latest version of my svnclient. from then, i'm not able to access the svn commands from terminal in my mac.
following is the error message i see in terminal

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/svn   Reason: image not found
>   Trace/BPT trap: 5

I'm using Mac OS 10.8.2

Kindly help me to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your local copy of "svn" (installed in /usr/local/bin) is dependent on a library that doesn't exist in /opt/local/lib anymore (which might have gone away when you uninstalled and re-installed the latest version of your svn client).

On my own machine, "`svn`" was installed into the "`/usr/bin`" directory via the Xcode command line tools, which you can download from Apple directly here ([look at the "Looking for additional developer tools?" link](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)) or you can install the command line tools directly from Xcode preferences (look in the "Downloads" tab, there will be a "Components" section).  Once you install the command line tools, you can them "rm" the copy of svn that's in "`/usr/local/bin`".

Comment: Thanks! I only had to install the additional developer tools.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same - reinstalled command line tools, then deleted the svn files from /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
brew install libssl
```

I once had similar problem with "libmagic", instead of "libssl", which was resolved by the "brew install" command.