# Change working copy path while committing code to SVN Server.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svnx

I am using SVNX for maintaining version of my code on SVN server. Problem is that i checked out my code from different server IP. While committing my code the server IP changes. Could anybody tell me how to change the server IP while committing my working copy.

Thanks N Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following terminal command.

```
cd PATH_OF_WORKING_COPY
svn switch --relocate OLD_URL NEW_URL
```

After doing this, you can continue with your new server.

Comment: Hi Bhargavi, Thanks for responding. I have tried above command but its saying "-bash: svn: command not found".

Comment: @VarunMehta looks svn is missing for terminal. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726870/not-able-to-use-svn-command-from-terminal-in-mac-os-10-8 or search for similar error on stack.